# How do i post to facebook a meassage with some lines and a space/s between the lines?

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms

```
private string PostFacebookWall(string accessToken, string message)
        {
            var responsePost = "";
            try
            {
                //create the facebook account object
                var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                parameters["message"] = message;
                responsePost = objFacebookClient.Post("feed", parameters).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responsePost = "Facebook Posting Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
            return responsePost;
        }

private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PostFacebookWall("", lineToPost + Environment.NewLine + "new line test");
        }
```

In the button click event i did that it will post the variable lineToPost which is a string with some text. And then i did that it will add a new line and also post the text " new line text "

But there is no space/empty line between the lineToPost and the " new line text " how do i add a space/empty line between them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want a blank line between ToPost and "new line text"?  If so, you can add another Environment.Newline:

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PostFacebookWall("", lineToPost + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine 
                                    + "new line test");
}
```

EDIT:  You could also add "\r\n" to the beginning of the "new line test" string.